Creating a function that acts differently in certain values of $x$
I'm trying to develop an increasing leveling system for a game that currently works according to the following formula:
$d \cdot (ax^2 + bx + c)$ = health_in_current_level
$d\;\Rightarrow$ base health value
$a\;\Rightarrow$ square coefficient
$b\;\Rightarrow$ linear coefficient
$c\;\Rightarrow$ intersection constant
The possible values for $x$ are 1 to 100 (players start at level 1, and finish at level 100).
Now for the tricky part, I've decided that I want to give the players a "checkpoint" every 10 levels, and instead of giving them the regular increase they get per level according to the formula, I want them to get triple the value they would have gotten if the formula would stay constant throughout the entire leveling process.
The problem is that I can't just multiply the value by 3 in that specific level because that would mean that the health value for level 10 will be larger than the value of level 11 (because the multiplication of that specific level will be higher than the formula at level 11).
So the question is whether there is any formula I can write (even if it's several formulae according to level ranges for example) that can create an always-increasing value that would get me the result I want.
If I were to try and imagine the graph of this function, it would be exponential growth (parabola?), and then at 10, it will jump, and continue with the same trajectory of exponential growth up to 20 and jump again, and so on.
How would I go about describing this sort of behavior in a formula?

Add a plot of what you want

What if, for level 10, you used $x=12$ instead, then, just kept incrementing from there? In other words, you go from level (1-100) to "effective" level, which goes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,24,25,26,...

@AlexK I think the OP wants the health increase from level 9 to level 10 to be triple the amount the increase would normally be if it followed the formula exactly. I don't think they intend for $h(10)$ to be $h(12)$, and then increase according to the formula from there

@AlexK This will effectively give the player the values for level 11->12 as the health, which isn't three times the value of 9->10. Hence, it's not exactly what I had in mind. but VV_721 gave a good answer I can use for my code.

I think I understand what you're saying. Let's have the function $f(x)=d\cdot(ax^2+bx+c)$, which is the formula you wrote. For levels 1-9, the function $f(x)$ applies exactly as it is. Now, the health increase from level 9 to level 10 must be triple the amount it would normally be if it followed $f(x)$ exactly. Therefore, we can say:
$\boxed{\text{Health at level 10}=f(9)+3\cdot(f(10)-f(9))}\;\Rightarrow$ We took the difference between $f(10)$ and $f(9)$, multiplied it by $3$, and added that to $f(9)$ to get the health at level 10.
From level 10 to level 19, the health will increase again according to the formula, but this time the graph starts at $f(9)+3\cdot(f(10)-f(9))$ instead of $f(10)$. To figure out how far upwards this vertical shift is, we need to find the difference between $f(9)+3\cdot(f(10)-f(9))$ and $f(10)$:
$f(9)+3\cdot(f(10)-f(9))-f(10)=2f(10)-2f(9)=\boxed{2(f(10)-f(9))}$
This means that the health for levels 10-19 is modeled by $f(x)+2(f(10)-f(9))$, and we'll call this $f_2(x)$.
Now, from level 19 to level 20, the health increase again is triple the normal amount. Therefore,
$\boxed{\text{Health at level 20}=f_2(19)+3(f_2(20)-f_2(19))}$
For levels 20-29, the health will increase according to $f_2(x)$, but the graph is just translated upwards by $2(f_2(20)-f_2(19))$. This means that the health for levels 20-29 is modeled by $f_2(x)+2(f_2(20)-f_2(19))$, which we can call $f_3(x)$.
From level 29 to level 30, the increase is triple the normal amount. Therefore,
$\boxed{\text{Health at level 30}=f_3(29)+3(f_3(30)-f_3(29))}$
Now do you understand the pattern? Do you think you can figure out the rest?

This is exactly what I had in mind, but couldn't figure out how to represent it correctly.
My main desire was to be able to describe Fn(X) using F(X) and the number of 10 steps that have passed. but since every function is derived from the previous function (sort of recursively) I guess this can't really be modeled into a single formula (at least not in a manner that I can see).
As I see it, every function Fn must iterate over all Fn=>1 in order to calculate itself, which I cannot denote in a single function (at least not with my capabilities).

Nice, I'm glad this was helpful. Indeed it would be satisfying to have a single formula that represents this entire trend.

The increase in health from level $x-1$ to level $x$ is
$$
d \cdot (ax^2 + bx + c)
 - d \cdot (a(x-1)^2 + b(x-1) + c)
\\
= d \cdot (a(2x-1) + b)\\
= d\cdot (2ax + b - a).
$$
You already get this increase from your formula, but you want to add another
$2d(2ax+b-a)=4adx+2d(b-a)$ as a “bonus” to health when $x$ is a multiple of $10.$
When $x=10n$ the accumulated total of these “bonuses” is
$20n(n+1)+2d(b-a)n.$
For any integer $x$ it’s
$$
h(x) = 20\lfloor x/10\rfloor(\lfloor x/10\rfloor+1)+2d(b-a)\lfloor x/10\rfloor. 
$$
You can add this to your basic formula.
